# No overload for method `CastSkill' takes `2' arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am very new in programming in Unity3d , i need little help in c#. My problem is im trying to cast skill without selecting monster.

so the code is:

```
    if (EventSkillFinished()) {
        var skill = skills[currentSkill];

        // apply the skill on the target
       **CastSkill(skill, target);**

        if (nextSkill != -1) {
            currentSkill = nextSkill;
            nextSkill = -1;
        } else currentSkill = skill.followupDefaultAttack ? 0 : -1;
```

and here's some code

```
  public void CastSkill(Skill skill) {
        if (CastCheckSelf(skill, false) && CastCheckTarget(skill)) {
            // do the logic in here or let the skill effect take care of it?
            if (skill.effectPrefab == null || skill.effectPrefab.isPurelyVisual) {
                // attack
                if (skill.category == "Attack") {
                    // deal damage directly
                    DealDamageAt(target, damage + skill.damage, skill.aoeRadius);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//This function takes one parameter:
public void CastSkill(Skill skill) { ... }

//This is passing two parameters:
CastSkill(skill, target);
```

What did you expect?

You need to create a new function that accepts two parameters, one for the skill being used and another for a Target of some `Type`.

Comment: someone said it to me " you  have to modify CastSkill to pass (skill, target) instead of just (skill). And then set target from in there, done." Sorry im not good in programming

Comment: @mhartiancruz You need to modify the `public void CastSkill(Skill skill)` part. Specifically, create a new function that takes two parameters.